# Problemas en validacion js ( contraseña no coinciden se redirige)

Tags: javascript, html

nueva en esto...estaba haciendo la validaciones con js, (es para un proyecto sipmple de tecnicatura,primer año), cuando la contraseña no coincide en vez de quedarse en la pagina me lo redirecciona a error file not found pero si funciona correctamente la redireccion y el alert cuando coinciden (el codigo que proporcioné), y por otro lado me pasa al revés cuando logro hacer andar que se quede en la página y salga que "las contraseñas no coinciden", cuando son iguales las contraseñas no me redirige al login(errorfilenotfound) pero si funciona el alert :) una mano?

## Registro de Usuario

```
<form action="/registro" method="post" class="form">
  // saco codigo que es irrelevante aca en el form no le puse ningun onsubmit

<script>
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  let password = document.getElementById('contrasena').value;
  let confirmPassword = document.getElementById('confirmar_contrasena').value;
  let passwordError = document.getElementById('password-error');
  let confirmPasswordError = document.getElementById('confirmar_contrasena-error');
  let valid = true;

  // Restablece los mensajes de error al inicio de cada envío del formulario.
  passwordError.textContent = '';
  confirmPasswordError.textContent = '';

  if (password === '') {
      passwordError.textContent = 'El campo de contraseña es obligatorio.';
      valid = false;
  } else if (password.length < 6 || password.length > 20) {
      passwordError.textContent = 'La contraseña debe tener entre 6 y 20 caracteres.';
      valid = false;
  }

  if (confirmPassword === '') {
      confirmPasswordError.textContent = 'El campo de confirmar contraseña es obligatorio.';
      valid = false;
  } else if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      confirmPasswordError.textContent = 'Las contraseñas no coinciden.';
      valid = false;
  }

  if (valid) {
    // Si la validación es correcta, muestra un mensaje y redirige al usuario.
    alert("¡Registro exitoso!");
    window.location.href = "login.html"; // Cambia "login.html" por la URL de la página de inicio de sesión.

    event.preventDefault(); // Evita que el formulario se envíe automáticamente.
  }
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

al ser `valid` igual a `false` tu codigo nunca entra en este bloque:

```
if (valid) {
    // Si la validación es correcta, muestra un mensaje y redirige al usuario.
    alert("¡Registro exitoso!");
    window.location.href = "login.html"; // Cambia "login.html" por la URL de la página de inicio de sesión.

    event.preventDefault(); // Evita que el formulario se envíe automáticamente.
  }
```

por lo que  `event.preventDefault()` nunca impide que el formulario se envie.